I am trying to add an image and a description next to it, what I should use
I am doing in app in flutter and I need in this specific Post detail to add an image and a description of what was used. Here it's what I am trying to achive 
and here is the code


class PostDetailState extends State<WorkoutPostDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: Container(
          height: 135,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10))),
            color: Colors.white,
            shadows: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      
                     
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                ])
              ])),
    );
  }
}



Any idea ?

You can create the Detail widget like this:
Container
  |__Row
      |__Image
      |__Column
           |__Text
           |__Text
           |__Text
           |__Text

Below is the code:
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
        Image.asset(
            vaultIcon,
            height: imageVaultHeight,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                    Text('Name Video Category'),
                    Text('30 videos'),
                    Text('Equipment used'),
                    Text('Type: HD'),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ],
),

Complete code below:

class PostDetailState extends State<WorkoutPostDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: Container(
        height: 135,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10))),
          color: Colors.white,
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              blurRadius: 5,
              spreadRadius: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'vaultIcon',
              height: 12,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10), // space between image & Column
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Name Video Category'),
                  Text('30 videos'),
                  Text('Equipment used'),
                  Text('Type: HD'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


